# Why the Player is walking through walls floor doors?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The MouseLook script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

/// MouseLook rotates the transform based on the mouse delta.
/// Minimum and Maximum values can be used to constrain the possible rotation

/// To make an FPS style character:
/// - Create a capsule.
/// - Add the MouseLook script to the capsule.
///   -> Set the mouse look to use LookX. (You want to only turn character but not tilt it)
/// - Add FPSInputController script to the capsule
///   -> A CharacterMotor and a CharacterController component will be automatically added.

/// - Create a camera. Make the camera a child of the capsule. Reset it's transform.
/// - Add a MouseLook script to the camera.
///   -> Set the mouse look to use LookY. (You want the camera to tilt up and down like a head. The character already turns.)
[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Mouse Look")]
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour {

    public enum RotationAxes { MouseXAndY = 0, MouseX = 1, MouseY = 2 }
    public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;
    private float sensitivityX = 5f;
    private float sensitivityY = 5f;

    private float minimumX = 0f;
    private float maximumX = 360f;

    private float minimumY = -30f;
    private float maximumY = 45f;

    private float rotationY = 0f;

    void Update ()
    {
        if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY)
        {
            float rotationX = transform.localEulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;

            rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp (rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, rotationX, 0);
        }
        else if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp (rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0);
        }
    }

    void Start ()
    {
        // Make the rigid body not change rotation
        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
    }
}
```

The controller script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

//[RequireComponent (typeof (Rigidbody))]
//[RequireComponent (typeof (BoxCollider))]

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    private void Update()
    {
        var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 150.0f;
        var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f;

        transform.Rotate(0, x, 0);
        transform.Translate(0, 0, z);
    }
}
```

When I use the mouse for example to look to the floor and move forward the player it will move through the floor.

I'm using box collider and I also tried to add a mesh collider but it didn't help so far.

The NAVI have a Rigidbody component attached to it.
I also had a Rigidbody attached to the Player and then he didn't walk through the floor but then the Rigidbody did problems with the doors. The doors opened/closed fast and many times with the Rigidbody.

[image: Player]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent two colliders from going through one another, you will have two options:

**1**.Use raycast to detect walls then manually adjust the position of the object or stop moving the player.

**2**.Use Rigidbody to automatically handle the collision then use `Rigidbody.MovePosition` and `Rigidbody.MoveRotation` to move and rotate the object instead of the `transform.Translate` and `transform.Rotate` used in your current code.

---

I prefer **#2** since it's easier to code and more reliable. Just attach `Rigidbody` and a collider to the player. Also attach collider to the walls and floors. The code below should move the player and it will not go through the walls.

```
public bool useWorldSpace;
public Rigidbody rb;
public float speed = 18;

public void Update()
{
    float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    //Movement
    Vector3 tempVect = new Vector3(0, 0, v);
    tempVect = tempVect.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    if (useWorldSpace)
        tempVect = transform.position + tempVect;
    else
        tempVect = transform.position + transform.TransformDirection(tempVect);


    rb.MovePosition(tempVect);

    //Rotation
    Vector3 angle = new Vector3(0, 100, 0);
    Quaternion deltaRot = Quaternion.Euler(angle * h * Time.deltaTime);
    rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * deltaRot);
}
```